# t-test vs linear regression: how are standard errors calculated?

Tags: regression, t-test, stata, standard-error, heteroscedasticity

Consider Stata's `auto` dataset. I am interested in finding the difference in the mean weight of foreign and domestic cars. To do this, I can do a two-sided unpaired t-test:

`ttest weight, by(foreign)`

or linear regression:

`reg weight foreign`

Both options provide the same absolute beta estimate (1001.206) and standard error (160.288).

**Case 1: Correcting for heteroskedasticity**

I can correct for heteroskedasticity by using a t-test assuming unequal variances:

`ttest weight, by(foreign) unequal`

or by using White standard errors in linear regression:

`reg weight foreign, robust`

Both options provide the same beta estimate as before. However, their standard errors differ: the t-test has a standard error of 133.495 and the linear regression has a standard error of 133.170.

*Question 1:* Assuming heteroskedasticity, does the t-test provide more accurate standard errors than the linear regression? Can we say that either method is in principle superior?

**Case 2: Singleton group**

Suppose that there is only one foreign car in the dataset:

```
sort foreign
drop if _n > 53
```

Then the t-test cannot estimate a standard error since the standard deviation of weight among foreign cars is undefined. In contrast, linear regression can estimate a standard error.

*Question 2:* In this scenario, does the t-test provide more accurate standard errors than the linear regression? Can we say that either method is in principle superior?

Comment: On the contrary, the (usual, vanilla) t-test *can* estimate a standard error when one group has just one member.  It uses the variance of the other group.  The result is equivalent to the regression answer.  That's because the (homoscedastic) t-test is equivalent to ordinary least squares regression.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the comment! Stata is producing a different result though:
`sysuse auto`
`sort foreign`
`drop if _n > 53`
`ttest weight, by(foreign)`
With this procedure (one foreign observation), the t-test does not estimate a standard error. Do you know what is happening?

Comment: You will need to consult with Stata about that.